# Adding a review box to site that posts to G+ Local page

Tags: google-plus, google-places-api, review

I was wondering if it was possible to add a review box to my site that would automatically post to my Google+ Local page, and in turn eventually show as a Google review.

I just want the simple functionality of leaving a comment and star rating to my site to avoid having to travel to another page.

Is this functionality available?

I have found a slight shortcut by adding the query parameter ?review=1 to the end of the url which automatically brings up the review box once the Google places page loads, and have customized a message to try and entice a click but feel that the easier you make it on someone to leave a review the more successful it will be.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry but we don't have that functionality.